# Work Around AWS ECS Fargate 10 Containers Per Task Definition Limit

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have about 11 containers that share data in the same volumes. I want to use Fargate so that I don't have to manually manage memory. But I couldn't put them to the same task definition because of ECS 10 containers per task definition limit. Is there a way to overcome this?

I also thought about using EFS as shared file system between containers but this is single point of failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a member of the AWS container team. It looks like EFS would be the way to go here. This is exactly the [type of use cases](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/developers-guide-to-using-amazon-efs-with-amazon-ecs-and-aws-fargate-part-1/) we built this integration for. Also note that EFS is not a SPOF because it's a [regional service and data is replicated across 3 different AZ with mount points in each AZ](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/developers-guide-to-using-amazon-efs-with-amazon-ecs-and-aws-fargate-part-2/). This means that should there be a problem in one of the AZ your application will continue to run on the remaining AZs and your data would still be fully available.